# How do you run rdoc on single files without overwriting all other files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation, rdoc, code-documentation

I am working on a very large rails project and I want to standardize the usage of rdoc in the codebase. I figured I could run it once over the whole project (to at least generate docs for the classes and methods themselves) and then devs can add single files as they add documentation.

The problem is that if I run `rdoc /path/to/some_file.rb`, it then removes all other files from the generated `index.html`, and only includes the one. Running rdoc on the whole project takes 3-4 minutes and it shouldn't be necessary to parse the entire project every time new comments are added. The output of `rdoc --help` provides no solutions.

Is there a way to configure rdoc such that it will always persist docs until I specifically run rdoc over those files again?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think rdoc removes anything from `index.html`, just overwrites it and isn't actually capable of modifying it. Regarding performance, I'm not 100% sure but most likely rdoc doesn't cache the parse results. [Yard](https://yardoc.org/) does, with `-c, --use-cache` option, and it speeds up things significantly.